# SKAction sequence temporary delay (initial delay?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, xcode6

So in the game I'm building I want to repeat an action, but I want it to have an initial delay. So for example, the action would execute three seconds after the user started the game, but after it executes for the first time, there's no longer a three second delay. What can I do to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a sequence with a wait and desired action and a run block, which the re-runs just the desired action wrapped in a repeat action

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Wow, that was easy. Thank you very much! You've helped me in a lot of questions!

Answer (score 7):

You could use an `SKAction` to make a delay, then put it at the beginning of your `sequence`.

[Apple gives](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/AddingActionstoSprites/AddingActionstoSprites.html) some sample code on sequences:

```
SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:100.0 duration:1.0];
SKAction *zoom = [SKAction scaleTo:2.0 duration:0.25];
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration: 0.5];
SKAction *fadeAway = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.25];
SKAction *removeNode = [SKAction removeFromParent];

SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp, zoom, wait, fadeAway, removeNode]];
[node runAction: sequence];
```

You can use `SKAction waitForDuration` to make a delay.