# Swift: random delay generation not working?

Tags: swift, random, sprite-kit

Ok, so I'm creating a sprite kit game and what I'm trying to do is generate a random `Double` and then feed it into an `SKAction.waitForDuration` so that a random delay is executed.

I'm using this delay to delay the spawning of my enemies within the game. Here is how I'm trying to generate and run a random delay:

```
func randomDelay() {
        var randLower : UInt32 = 1
        var randUpper : UInt32 = 50
        var randDelayTime = arc4random_uniform(randUpper - randLower) + randLower
        var randDelayTimer = Double(randDelayTime) / 10

        runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(randDelayTimer))
        println(randDelayTimer)
    }
```

Here I execute this function prior to spawning my enemy:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
            SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.runBlock({self.randomDelay()}),
                SKAction.runBlock({self.spawnEnemy1()})
)))
```

And the code doesn't crash but no delay is being executed. The enemies are just spawned over and over at the same rate.

I know that the `randomDelay()` function is producing a random `Double` because when I `println(randDelayTimer)`, I get a random `Double` every time like I should.

Why isn't the delay in `randomDelay()` being run? How can I fix this?

Comment: This other answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534390/skaction-sequence-temporary-delay-initial-delay

Comment: No that does not help me. I want my delay to be repeated forever along with the enemy spawn func. My problem is that my delay will not execute